# How to take specific elements on multiple lists on beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have trouble to extract some specific tags (and their string content) and store them into variables (so I can get these variables into a CSV file later).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/DFletcher1990/')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')

for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr'):
    tds=tr.find_all('td')
    print(tds)
```

I would like to collect :

- `"4 years ago"` and store it into a variable called `date`,
- `"932,915"` and store it into a variable called `points`,
- `"372"` and store it into a variable called `videos`.

I don't really understand how `bs4.element.ResultSet` behave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just treat it like a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/DFletcher1990/')
r.html.render(sleep=10)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
print(dates,points,videos,sep="\n")
```

Output

```
4 years ago
932,915
372
```